# qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available

Tags: virtualization, android, libraries, qemu

I'm trying to virtualize Android x86 on Ubuntu 20.10 with qemu-android provided by https://www.android-x86.org and I'm following this tutorial :

https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-7-1-r5.html

So I have issued these commands like explained on the tutorial :

```
sudo apt install alien
sudo alien -ci android-x86-7.1-r5.x86_64.rpm 
sudo qemu-android
```

and voila',this is what happens :

```
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
qemu-system-x86_64: Display 'sdl' is not available.
```

someone knows how to fix that ? Previously I have installed these packages on my ubuntu 20.10:

```
apt install libepoxy-dev libdrm-dev libgbm-dev libpulse-dev mesa-common-dev libgbm-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libvirglrenderer-dev libsdl2-dev
```

what's missing ? thanks.

UPDATE : I read that I should select gtk instead of SDL and I should also put gl=off. Infact with gl=on,this error happens :

```
Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/vda
gl_version 45 - core profile enabled
x86_64:/ # vrend_renderer_fill_caps: Entering with stale GL error: 1280
GLSL feature level 430
```

and it won't boot. So I have modified the file android-qemu like this :

https://pastebin.com/16PHkaum

but it does not work anyway. please give a look at these log messages :

https://pastebin.com/nBxZf0q9

Android stucks on boot,it won't boot.

[image]

Comment: Hiho Marietto, sdl1 was becoming way too umanitainable and unstable so the support for it was disabled in Debian and Ubuntu. In the meantime also upstream dropped support for it. There are (very few) special use cases which could benefit from SDL and we work on enabling that via sdl2 in bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsdl2/+bug/1256185 but this isn't  a high prio as there is the gtk backend which in 9/10 use cases is better anyway. Until then If you make your wrapper to use `-display gtk` instead of `-display sdl` you should be fine.

Comment: ok I did it. It does not work in any case. it freezes with the following error message :    
gl_version 45 - core profile enabled
x86_64:/ # vrend_renderer_fill_caps: Entering with stale GL error: 1280
GLSL feature level 430

Comment: for fixing this error I have put gl=off (I read to do like that somewhere). Infact android booted,but it stucks on boot. refresh the page. I have added more details.